# Haskell Refactoring Advice

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, refactoring

I am looking for some refactoring / Best practice advice on the following code. I would like to try to avoid the extensions while maintaining separate modules for different "versions" that are mutually exclusive. My current solution is to use a class and use existential quantification to create a common type for each of the `CountrySets`.

This is an easy thing for me to accomplish if I was using OOP, but I can't seam to think "functional" yet.

Thanks for your time.

**Province.hs**

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification, RankNTypes  #-}
module Province where

  class Country a where
    --some stuff that is not important

  data Power = 
    forall a. (Show a, Eq a, Country a) => Power a |
    Netural |
    Water

  data Unit = Unit {
    power  :: forall a. (Show a, Eq a, Country a) => a, 
    piece :: Piece

  data Piece = Tank | Plane

  data Province = Province {
    power  :: Power,
    provName :: String
  } deriving (Eq)

  instance Show Power where
    show (Power b) = "Power " ++ show b
    show (Netural) = "Netural"
    show (Water) = "Water"

  instance Eq Power where
    (==) a b = Prelude.show a == Prelude.show b
```

**Version1.hs**

```
import Province

  data CountrySet1 =
    Country11 |
      Country12 
    deriving (Eq, Show)
  instance Country CountrySet1 where

  provs = 
    one1:one2:[]

  one1 = Province (Power Country11) "Place11"
  one2 = Province (Power Country12) "Place12"
```

**Version2.hs**

```
import Province

  data CountrySet2 =
    Country21 |
    Country22 
      deriving (Eq, Show)
  instance Country CountrySet2 where

  provs = 
    two1:two2:[]

  two1 = Province (Power Country11) "Place21"
  two2 = Province (Power Country12) "Place22"
```

Comment: I think this is a good candidate for the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site. However, I don't use it myself so I'm not 100% certain it fits their criteria.

Comment: I'll post it there and see what I get.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to put class constraints in the data types.  You can instead parametrize your data type on the `a` variable so that you can place the constraints on the type-class instances themselves, like so:

```
-- Note that I added a type variable to "Power"
data Power a = Power a | Neutral | Water

instance (Show a) => Show (Power a) where ...

instance (Eq a) => Eq (Power a) where ...
```

... or you could do what most people do and use `deriving`:

```
data Power a = Power a | Neutral | Water deriving (Eq, Show)
```

This generates the exact same instances you wrote (except the `Eq` one will be much more efficient than what you wrote).  No extensions required!

Then if you want `a` to be a specific type, you just say so!

```
-- Version1.hs
myValue1 :: Power CountrySet1
myValue1 = ...


-- Version2.hs
myValue2 :: Power CountrySet2
myValue2 = ...
```

These are then completely compatible and both implementations can coexist alongside each other.

Comment: Also see [this post by Luke Palmer](http://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/11/23/encapsulation-considered-harmful/).

Comment: @Ptharien'sFlame Wow, that is really well written.  I'm bookmarking that for teaching.

Comment: How to I adjust `data Province { power  :: Power, ...` accordingly? (line 19, sorry I don't know how to display line numbers)

Comment: @Raisdead `data Province a  = Province { power :: Power a, ... }`

Comment: Of course! I guess I havn't made the connection yet that anything that starts with data construct is the same thing. Thanks a bunch!